# how to toggle audio loop attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I want to toggle audio loop attribute.

```
<audio id="player" controls><source src="lev.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
```

js

```
$("#btnloop").click(function(){
    var player = $("#player");
    if (player.loop == false) {player.loop = true}
    else {player.loop = false};
});
```

This doesn't work.
Solution for me maybe could be another SIMPLE player with a loop button embeded, if any.

Comment: what does `player.loop` output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop is a property of HTMLMediaElement. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/loop

Your player variable is the jQuery object so if you check your console you should have an error. Try this.

```
$("#btnloop").click(function(){
    var player = $("#player")[0];
    if (player.loop == false) {player.loop = true}
    else {player.loop = false};
});
```

Comment: Solved, thanks a lot, especially for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Why do not  continue to use jQuery?

```
$("#btnloop").click(function(){
     var player = $("#player");
     if (player.prop('loop') == false) {
        player.prop('loop', true);
     } else {
        player.prop('loop', false);
     };
});
```

Comment: I actually can't get this to work in Chrome. I came to this thread looking for a solution to `prop('loop',true)` not working.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, do you have any error in the console? Can you create a fiddle?  I'm going to bed, I wait for your info...  Bye

Comment: No error, just silent fail. I ended up writing my own looper using the "ended" event.